# what does parameter before method means in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 3, in a video tutorial I see use [parameter]. I want to know whats its name and whats its application?

what does [parameter] before method means?

```
 [parameter] 
 public int incrementgap{ get; set; } = 1;

    void inccount()

    { currentCount+=incrementgap; }
```

Comment: which parameter ?

Comment: sorry, i edit my post, see it again

Comment: It seems to be an Attribute but it is very uncommon in camelCase. Is that **exactly** what you have seen in the tutorial or is it just a **lookalike**?

Comment: And you placed that before a **property** and not before a **method** as you described in your question. That is confusing too

Comment: Did you use it in blazor?

Comment: what is example of parameter can you give some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Parameter]` is used to mark the component parameters that can be set when the component is used in another page.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#component-parameters

For more detailed exlpanation,in this code below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not add `[Parameter]` attribute, those are just public properties that can't be set from other pages.That is to say the following line would be invalid :

```
<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent" />
```

The correct way should be:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClickCallback">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClickCallback { get; set; }
}
```

Then it allows you could set the parameters whenever we use that component:

```
<ChildComponent Title="Panel Title from Parent"
                OnClickCallback="@ShowMessage">
    Content of the child component is supplied
    by the parent component.
</ChildComponent>
```

Comment: The question is - at its current state - about *parameter before method* and you answer about ParameterAttribute which is only valid for properties. Maybe you answered the question the OP has in mind but you did not answered the question he has asked ;o)